# Bash expression combined with return code from a command

Tags: bash

I want to test for a condition and if true run a command and if non-zero, execute the body of the `if`.

I've tried all manner of combinations of [] and -a and && and $() and cant figure it out. The attempt below gives error of: `[: too many arguments`

(This is just a simplified example, the question is also about understanding more about bash rather than solving a particular problem.)

```
numMd5Files=1

if [ ${numMd5Files} -eq 1 ] -a [ ! $( md5sum -c md5.txt ) ] ; then
    echo "md5 error"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need:

```
if [ ${numMd5Files} -eq 1 ] && md5sum -c md5.txt; then
```

The number of files must be 1 and the `md5sum` command must be successful for the `then` block to be executed.  You may end up redirecting the output of `md5sum` to `/dev/null` so you don't see what it says:

```
if [ ${numMd5Files} -eq 1 ] && md5sum -c md5.txt >/dev/null 2>&1; then
```

And if you're only interested in `md5sum` failures, then the exit status of `md5sum` can be inverted with the Bash built-in `!` command:

```
if [ ${numMd5Files} -eq 1 ] && ! md5sum -c md5.txt; then
```

The `if` command simply tests the exit status of commands.  When you use `[`, the `[` command is executed and produces an zero or non-zero exit status.  If the exit status is 0, it is successful, and the `then` clause is executed.  If the exit status is not 0, it fails, and the `elif` or `else` clause (if present) is executed instead.

There is often an external command `/bin/test` aka `/bin/[` — but most modern shells also have a built-in variant of `test` and `[` that is executed in preference to the external command.

With the `&&` operator, the command on the left is executed; if it is successful, the command on the right is executed, and if it is successful too, the `then` clause is executed.

The `[[` operator is only available as a built-in to the shell.

I still have the code for an external command `not` (first version in 1991), which I used to use sometimes, and could be installed with a link named `!`, so that for shells without a built-in `!` command, I could still invert the exit condition of a command.  It is not very complex!

Comment: Thanks very much, especially for the detailed explanation. (I had to add a `!` before the `md5sum` command as I want to run the `then` clause if there is an md5 error. Tried to edit your answer but SO will not let me).

Comment: The history you so casually toss around in some of your answers constantly astonishes me. =)